# I want to reach out to and network with Magento professionals. Where can I do that?

Tags: magento2

The Magento community in my area is less than thriving. Is there a place I can network with other professionals and grow my knowledge base.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a complete list of all major Magento events taking place in August. Most of them have some seriously impressive speakers lined up, along with free food and drinks.

Have fun!

http://cedcommerce.com/blog/magento-events-august-networking/